# How do I delete the oldest file in a backup folder if there is more than 15 files in the folder after I made the new backup using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

How do I delete the oldest file in a backup folder if there is more than 15 files in the folder after I made the new backup using vbscript?

I found that my Backups take up plenty of space on my hdd

Is it possible to do it by counting the number of files in a folder? My backups are named "ST-06.02.18 07h20.zip" . I can always change the name if it wil make it easier...xd

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDirectory, dNow, yy, mt, dd, hh, nn, objShell, dOpen
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strDirectory = "c:\test\"

If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
   WScript.Echo strDirectory & " already created "
Else
   Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
   WScript.Echo "Just created " & strDirectory
End If



dNow = Now
yy = Right(Year(dNow), 2)
mt = Right("00" &Month(dNow), 2)
dd = Right("00" &Day(dNow), 2)
hh = Right("00" &Hour(dNow), 2)
nn = Right("00" &Minute(dNow), 2)
ss = Right("00" &Second(dNow), 2)



Compress "C:\Program Files\ST\Db" ,strDirectory & "ST-" &dd & "." &mt & "." &yy & " " &hh & "h" &nn &".zip"

Sub Compress(Input, ZipFile)
Dim Shell : Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim FSO : set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
FSO.CreateTextFile(ZipFile, true).WriteLine "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
Set ZipFile = Shell.NameSpace(ZipFile) 
ZipFile.CopyHere Input
Do Until ZipFile.items.Count = 1 
'important, makes the script not fall out and dispose of objects before they are done
'items.count is the amount of root items you anticipate to be in the zip file
        wscript.sleep 200
Loop
Set Shell = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set ZipFile = Nothing
End Sub

Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
dOpen = "explorer.exe /e," & strDirectory
objShell.Run  dOpen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set F = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\David Candy\Desktop\New Folder\Stories\Test")

If F.size > 2^30 Then
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        With rs
            .Fields.Append "Date", 7 
            .Fields.Append "Txt", 201, 5000 
            .Open

            For Each Thing in f.files
                .AddNew
                .Fields("Date").value = thing.datelastmodified
                .Fields("Txt").value = thing.path
                .UpDate
            Next
            .Sort = "Date Desc"
            Do While not .EOF
                fso.deletefile  .Fields("Txt").Value
                msgbox f.size
                If f.size < 2^30 then Exit Do
                .MoveNext
            Loop
        End With
End If
```

This sample code runs when the folder is greater than 2 gig and deletes the oldest files until under 2 gig.

It uses a disconnected recordset created in memory to sort files by last modified.

Comment: Is it possible to do it by counting the number of files in a folder? My backups are named "ST-06.02.18 07h20.zip" . I can always change the name if it wil make it easier...xD

Comment: You are supposed to be a VBScript programmer to ask questions about VBScript. Did you look up any of the objects above to see what else you can do with them. In Google type *ADODB.Recordset site:msdn.com*, etc.

Comment: Edit your question with this.

Comment: I'm a noob... xD

Comment: That's ok as long as you make an effort. Edit your question. Look in help.

Comment: There is an edit link under your question. Paste your code in, select it, press Ctrl + K.

Comment: Got it now... first time use of this site